How to add a color when a button is pressed without ripple effect?
I want to remove ripple effect from button, but still have onSurface color on it.
For example, this is button before pressing

i want to achieve this after pressing button.

Here is my current code.
val MyRippleConfiguration =
            RippleConfiguration(color = Color.Red, rippleAlpha = RippleAlpha(0f,0f,0f,0f))
        CompositionLocalProvider(LocalRippleConfiguration provides MyRippleConfiguration){
            Button(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().padding(4.dp).bounceClickEffect(),
                onClick = {
                }) {
                Text(
                    text = "Sign up free",
                    color = colorResource(id = R.color.black),
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                    fontSize = 16.sp
                )
            }
        }

fun Modifier.bounceClickEffect() = composed {
    var isPressed by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val scale by animateFloatAsState(if (isPressed) 0.98f else 1f)

    this
        .graphicsLayer {
            scaleX = scale
            scaleY = scale
        }
        .pointerInput(isPressed) {

            awaitPointerEventScope {
                isPressed = if (isPressed) {
                    waitForUpOrCancellation()
                    false
                } else {
                    awaitFirstDown(false)
                    true
                }
            }
        }
}

i tried to change values of RippleAlpha object but i were unable to achieve it.

I were able to achieve the questions in two ways.

First solution provided by how-to-change-button-background-color-on-click

Here is the solution in my case.
var color by remember { mutableStateOf(Color.White) }

    TextButton(modifier = Modifier
        .bounceClickEffect(Color.Transparent, Color.Transparent)
        .pointerInteropFilter {
            when (it.action) {
                MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                    color = Color.Gray
                }

                MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                    color = Color.White
                }
            }
            true
        },onClick ={
    }, colors = ButtonDefaults.textButtonColors(containerColor = Color.Transparent)){
        Text(text="Log in", fontSize = 16.sp,fontWeight =  FontWeight.Bold, color = color)
    }


Second solution is to use animateColorAsState on Modifier
 fun Modifier.bounceClickEffect(pressedColor:Color,releasedColor:Color) = 
 composed {
 var isPressed by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
 val scale by animateFloatAsState(if (isPressed) 0.98f else 1f)
 val backgroundColor by animateColorAsState(if (isPressed) pressedColor else 
 releasedColor)

 this
    .graphicsLayer {
     scaleX = scale
     scaleY = scale
 }
 .background(
     color = backgroundColor,
     shape = RoundedCornerShape(20.dp)
 ) // Apply color to background
 .pointerInput(isPressed) {

     awaitPointerEventScope {
         isPressed = if (isPressed) {
             waitForUpOrCancellation()
             false
         } else {
             awaitFirstDown(false)
             true
         }
     }
 }
 .height(40.dp)
 }



I just specify a lighter shade at the beginning then a darker shade

check this doc out.
for example try this one:
private object DisabledRippleThemeColorAndAlpha : RippleTheme {

    @Composable
    override fun defaultColor(): Color = Color.Red

    @Composable
    override fun rippleAlpha(): RippleAlpha = MyRippleAlpha
}

    CompositionLocalProvider(LocalRippleTheme provides DisabledRippleThemeColorAndAlpha) {
        Button {
            // ...
        }
    }

or
private object DisabledRippleTheme : RippleTheme {

    @Composable
    override fun defaultColor(): Color = Color.Transparent

    @Composable
    override fun rippleAlpha(): RippleAlpha = RippleAlpha(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f)
}

// ...
    CompositionLocalProvider(LocalRippleTheme provides DisabledRippleTheme) {
        Button {
            // ...
        }
    }


Thanks for your time, i tried these solutions but when i press the button i don't get any ripple effect or a color, the button stay the same before pressing. I just want to disable ripple effect but not color.

@FatimaJamal try
@ Composable
override fun defaultColor(): Color = Color.Red

@ Composable
override fun rippleAlpha(): RippleAlpha = RippleAlpha(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f)

}
this has to work
